# Android action bar removing home icon with light theme reverts to blue divider

Tags: java, android, xml

I and using the light holo theme and it normally has a grey divider bar below it but I then decided to remove my home icon from the action bar and it reverted back to the blue color divider found in the dark theme. How can I get the grey one back?

My code is as such:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">        
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
```